# How to run function in while loop until it returns true?

Tags: php, arrays

I think the code itself that I wrote to try and get this working is pretty self explanatory. First time I'm using a while loop, I did search other similar questions, and also [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp) yet I can't figure this one out.

Right now, the code is only running once for some reason, if for some random chance the number from array_rand is 6 then it returns **yes**, otherwise it won't even echo **no** when it should since it's inside the while loop, but clearly I'm wrong.

```
/**
* Check if param number is between 5 and 7
* @param {int} $number - number
*/
function check($number){
  if($number >= 5 && $number <= 7){
    return array('message' => 'Number is between the min and the max');
  }

  return false;
}

// Random numbers for testing 
$info = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

// Get a random number from the array
$info_rand = $info[array_rand($info)];

// run function by passing a random number from the array
$run_loop = check($info_rand);

// here we should keep running the function until it returns true then break, otherwise just echo no so we know it's running
while(true){
  if($run_loop){
    echo 'Yes';
    break;
  } else {
    echo 'no';
  }
}
```

https://eval.in/953478

Comment: $run_loop is a variable you set once. Out side the loop. It's not false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following change:

```
/**
* Check if param number is between 5 and 7
* @param {int} $number - number
*/
function check($number){
  if($number >= 5 && $number <= 7){
  return array('message' => 'Number is between the min and the max');
 }

 return false;
}


// Random numbers for testing 
$info = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
// here we should keep running the function until it returns true then 
// break, otherwise just echo no so we know it's running
while(true){

   // Get a random number from the array
   $info_rand = $info[array_rand($info)];

   // run function by passing a random number from the array
   $run_loop = check($info_rand);
   if($run_loop){
     echo 'Yes';
     break;
   } else {
    echo 'no';
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you overwrite the `$info` array every time you loop?

Answer (score 1):

nothing is changing the $run_loop variable

```js
/**
* Check if param number is between 5 and 7
* @param {int} $number - number
*/
function check($number){
  if($number >= 5 && $number <= 7){
    return array('message' => 'Number is between the min and the max');
  }

  return false;
}

// Random numbers for testing 
$info = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

// here we should keep running the function until it returns true then break, otherwise just echo no so we know it's running
while(true){
  //this will randomize each time
  //before it would never change
  if(check($info[rand(0,count($info))])){
    echo 'Yes';
    break;
  } else {
    echo 'no';
  }
}
```